# jQuery bounce effect

Tags: jquery

Hi I'm looking to make a modal div appear on a page using a bounce effect like seen on the iPhone for its pop-up messages.

By bounce I mean like scale bigger than normal and then become the actual size in an elasticated way whilst fading into view.

Any ideas on where to start with this?

Comment: Have you looked at the various things you can do with basic jQuery animation?

Comment: Any solution for this question?

Answer (score 5):

I'd start with the [easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/). The demo on the home page there seems pretty close to what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

I start by playing with the different effects in the easing plugin: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot scale HTML elements properly by a factor (this looks weird), i recommend a simpler approach. Simply set `overflow: hidden` and animate the size of the element accordingly. This is not going to look as nice as the native dialogs, but it comes close. You can use the [jQuery easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) for the bounce animation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use CSS3 animation techniques such as scale3d and mix it with opacity.